# Azure web app gateway authentication

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web App in Azure in a resource group with a Gateway in the new App Service. How can I use that gateway to manage authentication for my web app?

There is plenty of articles on protecting an API App with the gateway, but none that I have found for Web Apps (previously known as Azure Websites)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you would need a mechanism for validating tokens from the App Service Gateway. API Apps get their tokens validated by the gateway itself, but other sites (Web Apps & Mobile Apps) receive no such help.

For Mobile Apps (a variant of Web Apps), token validation logic is provided by the Mobile Apps Server SDK, but this is admittedly a bit much for the given scenario (worth pointing out that updates are coming which will make the Mobile Apps SDK easier to work with in any web app, though).

If you were to use the Mobile SDK in your web app, you would need to set the `MS_SigningKey` app setting for your site. You can get this by navigating from the gateway blade to the "Gateway Host" site and inspecting it's app settings.

Comment: I'm actually from the App Service team, and we are aware of this scenario and are working to address it in a better way than I described above. No details to share now, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if there is an idea on the http://feedback.azure.com site I can follow for updates on this?

Comment: There isn't one that I'm aware of. Please feel free to create a new suggestion for this.

Comment: Are these the mentioned updates mattchenderson http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/17/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/ ? Would the recommended solution then be to use MVC inside the Mobile App for web and use the mobile service client SDK for login from JS/HTML?

Comment: That is a valid approach, but we are working to eventually make it even easier than that. We don't want to force users to create Mobile Apps if they just want web.